# How To define a Priority (High/Medium/Low) of SQL Server User?

Tags: sql-server

A User have low Priority to execute any Query Means, At the certain Time Period the session id killed own self(automatically).

Means,I tried to make a server role (name like: Low_priority_server_role) which define lowest priority of the user. If I map a user with  that server role then user can execute a select query but the Execution time not greater than 45 sec.

Comment: This question makes no sense at all I'm afraid. you need to elaborate a lot more than a couple of lines.

Comment: I concur with Lamu. Provide us with what you've tried, etc.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-query-governor-cost-limit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Off-topic for SO - belongs on dba perhaps.